# Using jquery scrollTop to position absolute Div

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I am trying to position an Absolute DIV using Jquery, depending on where the user is clicking on the page.

At the moment this works just great

```
$('#window').css('left', jsEvent.pageX);
$('#window').css('top', jsEvent.pageY);
```

This positions the element exactly where my mouse has clicked the screen...

Until you scroll down that is. That is why I am trying to achieve something that will take the amount of pixels from the top of the page into account. I thought something like this...

```
$('#window').css('top', jsEvent.pageY + scrollTop());
```

would do the trick, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Any hints?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely works in Firefox. As such, it should work in Chrome, Safari and Opera. IE however, I'm not entirely sure. Give it a shot.

```
$('#window').css({
    left: e.clientX
    , top: e.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop
});
```

**EDIT: This new version should work in most, if not all browsers.**

```
var rxp = /webkit/gi;

$('#window').css({
   left: e.clientX
   , top: e.clientY + rxp.test(window.navigator.userAgent) ? document.body.scrollTop : document.documentElement.scrollTop
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fix the issue. I see no difference in the result compared to my original code. Any other ideas?

Comment: I just alerted the document.documentElement.scrollTop and it is still on zero when i scroll down.

Comment: Still no. Maybe its because these are being called within a callback. But I didn't think that would matter. Points for trying  though :)